# I need to rebind in Grid-view after every record completed in for loop process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I try to import the records from csv and binding into grid.Then every records process for other details. In this case I need to update the UI after every record completed.

```
 WebscrapeSettings objweb = new WebscrapeSettings();
        var dtcontact = GetDataTableFromCsv(@"D:\\(1-5) DEN.csv", true);           
        if (dtcontact.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string starttime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            for (int ic = 0; ic < dtcontact.Rows.Count; ic++)
            {
                objweb.SearchType = "Company Linked In";
                objweb.ContactName = dtcontact.Rows[ic]["Contact"].ToString();
                objweb.Location = dtcontact.Rows[ic]["LinkedInLocation"].ToString();
                objweb.Title = dtcontact.Rows[ic]["Title"].ToString();
                objweb.SearchString = "";
                objweb.EmailDomain = "";
                objweb.Company = dtcontact.Rows[ic]["Company"].ToString();

                string result = "";
                var t = WebScrape(objweb);
                if (t.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var pair in t)
                    {
                        divnormal.InnerHtml = ic + "-" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "-" + "<br/> <br/> <br/>" + divnormal.InnerHtml;// +"<br/> <br/> <br/>" + pair.Value;
                        
                    }
                }
                //I want to rebind the Grid Here
                 BindImportfileDetails();
                 BindImportrecordsdetails(ImportFileID);
            }
            string endtime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: you want to perform some dynamic calculation during grid binding?

Comment: No , each record processed for web scrap, Once record completed the process, I want to update status in UI.